# the file-system of kvm virtual machine went to read-only after live migration

Tags: kvm-virtualization, migration, glusterfs

I setup my kvm virtualization environment with GlusterFS, the topology as follows:

**KVM1** ---------- **KVM2** --------------**KVM3**

**|**----------------------**|**-------------------------**|**

-----------------------**|**-------------------------

--------------**|**------------------**|**----------------

-------**GlusterFS1**---**GlusterFS2**----------

the description of setup as follows:

## Mount GlusterFS

three kvm machines mount glusterfs with command:

/sbin/mount -t glusterfs -o sync,direct-io-mode=enable gfs1.dalegames.com:/gfs /gfs

## Creating file type disk for virtual machine

qemu-img create -f qcow2 /gfs/vs_data/linux 100G  #For Linux virtual machine

qemu-img create -f qcow2 /gfs/vs_data/windows 100G  #For Windows virtual machine

## Installing Virtual Machine

## Installing Linux Virtual Machine

virt-install --ram=4096 --vcpus=4 --os-type=linux --os-variant=rhel6 \
         --cdrom /gfs/ISOs/RHEL_Server_6.5_x86_64_DaleVS.iso --network bridge=br0 \
         --disk path=/gfs/vs_data/linux,format=qcow2 --accelerate --vnc  \
         --name=linux --noautoconsole

## Installing Windows Virtual Machine

virt-install --ram=4096 --vcpus=4 --os-type windows --os-variant=win2k8 \
         --cdrom /gfs/ISOs/Win2k8.iso --network bridge=br0 \
         --disk path=/gfs/vs_data/windows,format=qcow2,bus=virtio --disk /gfs/ISOs/virtio-win-disk.vfd,device=floppy\
         --accelerate --vnc \
         --name=windows --noautoconsole --hvm

## Live Migrating Virtual Machine and the Question

[root@kvm1 ~]# virsh migrate --live --verbose *linux* qemu+ssh://kvm2/system

root@kvm2's password:

Migration: [100 %]

**At this time, the file-system of linux virtual machine went to read-olny mode.**

But when I live migrate a windows virtual machine, all works well.

Anyone can help me to fix it. thanks a lot!

Comment: the error messages:


Message from syslogd@newvs at Jan  8 22:33:01 ...


 kernel:journal commit I/O error

Comment: Looks like a storage level issue, if the VM didn't get paused, that means qemu io calls went through, but the guest OS still felt a glitch, hence the switch to r/o. check the storage level logs for this time on both hosts

Comment: What is the ownership on your images after migration?  Apparently, Libvirt doesn't detect glusterfs as a shared filesystem like it does NFS or Samba, so when a VM migrates away, the original host will chown root:root the disk image.  Since the receiving host is running the VM as qemu:qemu (on RHEL6/CentOS6, at least), the image on glusterfs is now read-only to the VM.  See:  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1057645#c7

Answer (score 2):

my kvm os is ubuntu 18.04,  and I use

```
sudo fsck -y /dev/sda
sudo reboot
```

then all works good!

Answer (score 0):

I have KVM OS Ubuntu 18.04 and host OS centOS.

I faced the same issue and upon doing little bit research on net, unmounting followed by remounting and then rebooting worked for me.

```
umount /dev/sda1
sudo fsck -y /dev/sda1
sudo reboot
```